# How do I calculate the discrepancy percentage between two columns with Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

| Date | GoogleAnalytics_PVS | AdobeAnalytics_PVS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6-3-2020 | 4802 | 4922 |
| 6-4-2020 | 5939 | 5932 |
| 6-5-2020 | 5122 | 5298 |

I have a table structured like the one above where it returns the number of page views from two sources. Ideally, I would like another column that would return a discrepancy percentage.

Am I overthinking it or could I just do something like

```
df['Discrep_%'] = (df['GoogleAnalytics_PVS'] - df['AdobeAnalytics_PVS'] / df['GoogleAnalytics_PVS']) x 100
```

Is there a better method, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Not the topic but is should not there be ( ) around the sub?

Comment: `(df['col1']-df['col2'])/df['col1'] * 100` is good

Answer (score 1):

> complexity wise it's the same, but here is another way. hence there can be multiple ways but the one you are applying is also the better.

```
df_new = [df[df.columns.difference(['GoogleAnalytics_PVS', 'AdobeAnalytics_PVS'])]/df['GoogleAnalytics_PVS'] ]*100

df_new
```